# Get documents from an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was checking [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) about how to query an array of embedded documents. They give you this example:

```js
{ item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
```

I want to get only the documents that has *qty* exactly equals to 5, so I did the following:

```js
db.inventory.find( { 'instock.qty': { $eq: 5 } } )
```

But it returned:

```js
{ "_id": ObjectId("5e8eda05efe2c455125b60da"), item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
{ "_id": ObjectId("5e8eda05efe2c455125b60db"), item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
{ "_id": ObjectId("5e8eda05efe2c455125b60dd"), item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
```

Why I am getting those documents which clearly doesn't have *qty* equals to 5, how can I prevent it)? Also, how can I avoid getting the `_id` field?

Comment: running fine for me. I'm getting doc of `journal`, `notebook`& `planner` which contain qty=5

Comment: My mongo version is `3.6.16`

Comment: I'm using `4.2` mongo version.